# Qt5 Multimedia Backends specifying

Tags: qmediaplayer, qt5.5

On Windows, I saw that there are at least two media services in the Qt's plugins: dsengine (DirectShow) and wmfengine (Media Foundation) for playing videos (https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_5.5.0_Multimedia_Backends).
How can we know which media services backend being used? And how to specify the media service backend to use programmatically

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I am having the same issue!

Comment: Not yet. I skipped this.

Comment: I know this is really old but the only way to change the backend is recompiling Qt with the ```-mediaplayer-backend wmf``` flag. At the moment (Qt 5.10.0) there is no way to switch backends programmatically.

Comment: The only way I found to switch from ```dsengine``` to ```wmfengine``` is by removing ```dsengine```.